# Cannot recover from sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Recently I updated my PC from Win7/8 to Win10, and I replaced an old graphic card with a rtx 3060. Since then, every time my laptop goes into sleep mode, is unable to recover.

When pressing a key, I hear the hardware running again, but the keyboard stops answering (lock buttons won't toggle led status), and the screen stays in black.

Does anyone happen to know what can be causing this issue?
I've checked event viewer but didn't manage to find anything that might look related.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly did you replace and upgrade a GPU in a laptop? We’re you running Windows 7 or Windows 8 when you performed the upgrade?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a regular PC. First I upgraded the OS, then replaced the GPU if I remember correctly.

Comment: I have a similar question. But I've had Win 10 and my graphics card for a long time. https://superuser.com/q/1692672/74576

Answer (score 0):

> updated my [computer] from Win7/8 to Win10, ... with a [new] rtx 3060
> [graphics card].

If this can be fixed with this machine, update BIOS (UEFI), Chipset,Video and Power Drivers.

If updating drivers does not work, use the old graphics card.

Finally it may be time to replace the computer with a newer one. (Not all older computers properly support Windows 10)

Comment: I think it only happens since the GPU change, but going back to the old one isn't an option, any idea what can be causing the issue, and how to address it?

Comment: Possible incompatibility with Power Management or Chipset.

Answer (score 0):

### Disable hibernation

Go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` and select "Change advanced power settings" under Sleep>Hibernate after, change "On Battery" to 0

Comment: Hibernation being enabled shouldn't cause this problem. Windows is supposed to support both sleep and hibernation.