# Windows 10 has black screen upon waking from sleep

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep

This doesn't happen every time but happens enough to be annoying.

Sometimes when I move my mouse to wake my PC from sleep, I can hear that it woke, but the monitor stays completely black.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd> seems to have no effect. Nothing seems to help at all except powering down the PC and turning it back on.

I'm wondering if Event Viewer shows somewhere what the problem was? I've looked but haven't found anything (but don't know where to look or what for).

My BIOS and drivers and Windows are up to date. I do *not* want to disable sleep or hibernation.

Comment: How old is the monitor? This sounds like the capacitors on your monitor are starting to fail or a bad video cable (HDMI?). Do you have an alternate monitor you can swap it out with to test? An alternate high quality video cable?  When the monitor has been asleep for awhile, is the room colder than it has been recently — perhaps because you are in winter now?

Comment: @spaceman-spiff Thanks for your response. I strongly doubt it's the monitor or cable, which is <2 yrs old and is a Dell U4320Q 42.5-inch. I don't have a 2nd monitor to try. I think I've already tested a different HDMI cable (which didn't prevent the problem), but I can try again to be sure. It seems like https://superuser.com/q/1691395/74576 is a similar problem.

Comment: Similar issues have been traced to driver updates, e.g. https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/183482/black-screen-waking-up-from-sleep-after-gpu-driver/ , and to Windows updates, e.g., https://www.errorsdoc.com/black-screen/fix-windows-10-black-screen-after-sleep/ . One suggested fix is to disable *Fast Startup*, which should *not* affect Hibernation and Sleep modes of shutdown.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Ryan, if any work, you can answer your own question... it would help others, too.